# (Free) optimization programs for .Net-programs

Tags: .net, optimization

What are the good (free) optimization programmers, .Net programmers need to have to optimize their programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good profiler, such as [EQATEC Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler). It'll help you identify sections of your code that take a while to execute, which you can then spend some time optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

I work in .Net, and the only profiler I've ever needed is the debugger itself, because it has a "pause" button. [This is why it works.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) One might think that the problem is some routine needs optimizing. What I always find is the time goes into things like: loading plugins, loading strings from resources, registering menu items, building data structure, and other administrivia. It's not that some routine needs tweaking, it's that too many of these boilerplate things are going on, and if you look, they don't all need to be.